# Build Shaded Java (jar) into a Win32 executable with Embedded JRE?

Tags: java, maven, winapi

So far what I've tried is Launch4j which I did not have success making it work. Always getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

Is there a way build a shaded Jar into a Win32 executable (console app) with embedded JRE with Maven. So user would not have to install Java?

Comment: Did you try using a plugin for Launch4j? E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18954002/2492865 or https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the maven-shade-plugin with launch4j-maven-plugin and made it working by making sure the target jar is the shaded jar:

`<jar>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar</jar>`

Answer (score 1):

You may use maven-shaded-plugin in combination with [launch4j-maven-plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin)

[here](http://www.hascode.com/2012/08/creating-a-windows-executable-from-a-jar-using-maven/) is good example of this